# How to use iptables REDIRECT correctly?

Tags: nat

im facing an issue with iptables port redirection.

I want to type in my browser 192.168.0.11 (later on with DNS) and this traffic should be redirected to 192.168.0.11:10000 (Webmin for DNS-Server).

My Setup:
Host interface: enp3s0

```
Host IP: 192.168.0.10, IP Alias (via Netplan): 192.168.0.11

on 192.168.0.10 is Openmediavault listening. 

on 192.168.0.11 is Openmediavault listening bc of the Ip Alias
```

now i want all traffic comming to 192.168.0.11 routed to 192.168.0.11 PORT 10000

My actual iptables looks like:

```
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      752 53469 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2        0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.11         tcp dpt:80 to:192.168.0.11:10000
3        0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  enp3s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.11         tcp dpt:80 redir ports 10000
```

But it does not work?

Comment: Since it already looks like you are running Docker, sure seems like it might be better to just run a proxy instead to map incoming http/https requests to the correct ports.

Comment: Anyway REDIRECT is almost certainly not what you want. It isn't an http redirect, and it is a very specialized port redirect. You probably just need a simple DNAT rule. Also `iptables -L` isn't the best way to list/share rules, the output of `iptables-save` tends to be a lot more useful.

Comment: Thank you! I managed it with a proxy.